# Problema al enviar o recibir petición POST (Front-end / Back-end), con Nest Framework en el servidor

Tags: javascript, post

Gracias a un amigo que me habló acerca de Nest Framework (https://nestjs.com) para hacer servicios, he logrado hacer unos cuantos (GET y POST). Resulta que al consumir un servicio POST que valida un usuario para iniciar sesión, desde una aplicación móvil con React-Native, todo funciona bien y eso me alegra mucho, sin embargo, cuando fui a hacer lo mismo en la web, sin saber por qué, no funcionó:

**Front-End**
*React.js*

```
var data = {
      'correo': 'sofia@serv.com',
      'contrasena': 'Sofia'
    }
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/signin', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(error => console.warn('Eerror:', error))
```

**Back-End**

```
...
@Controller('/users')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private userservice: UserService) {}
    @Post('/signin')
    public async signIn(
        @Request() req,
        @Response() res,
        @Body('correo') correo,
        @Body('contrasena') contrasena
    ) {
        console.log(req.body);
        const user = await this.userservice.signIn(correo, contrasena)
        res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(user)
    }
...
```

**Respuesta**

Cuando hago:

```
console.log(req.body);
```

Muestra

```
{ '{"correo":"sofia@serv.com","contrasena":"Sofia"}': '' }
```

**Alternativa**

Hoy, "experimentado" una cosa y otra, se me ocurrió hacer lo siguiente:

```
var data = {
  'correo': 'sofia@serv.com',
  'contrasena': 'Sofia'
}
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/signin', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: 'correo=' + data.correo + '&&contrasena=' + data.contrasena,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(error => console.warn('Eerror:', error))
```

**Respuesta**

Resulta que funcionó porque la respuesta fue:

```
{ correo: 'sofia@serv.com', contrasena: 'Sofia' }
```

Mi pregunta ahora es, por qué tuve que hacer:

```
body: 'correo=' + data.correo + '&&contrasena=' + data.contrasena
```

Aunque está funcionando, me gustaría poder arreglar esto, si alguien me pudiera dar una respuesta, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: **Back-End**

> nest --version
> 5.3.0

Comment: **Front-End (React.js)**
>16.4.1